# integrate rational function using only u-sub

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{3-3z^{2}}{1-z^{4}}dz$

I have tried $z^{4}$ as the $u$ but it just won't work!

Help, please?

Comment: You can simplify this expression. There's a term in the numerator which is also in the denominator.

Comment: Numerator: 3(1-z^2); denominator : (1-z^2)(1+z^2); Helps a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{3-3z^2}{1-z^4}=\frac{3(1-z^2)}{(1+z^2)(1-z^2)}=\frac3{1+z^2}\text{ for }z\ne\pm1$$
Hence this is just
$$\int\frac3{1+z^2}\mathrm{d}z=3\arctan{(z)}+C\text{ for }z\ne\pm1$$